# Notepad++: Text block too big for Find and Replace

Tags: notepad++

I did a search but couldn't find an answer. I'm currently using Notepad++ to do some text editing. I need to replace a couple blocks of text with a very LARGE block of text. The block of text I want to replace with is too large for the replace text box. Is there a workaround for this? Or possibly another program that can handle large find and replacing?

Answer (score 0):

EditPad Pro has a gigantic find/replace window.  I wish this were the case for Notepad++.

http://www.editpadpro.com/